# Как редактировать файлы в контейнере Docker на Windows?

Tags: windows, docker

впервые имею дело с Докером, установил Докер Десктоп для Виндоус 10, контейнеры подымаются из образов, все работает, но как мне редактировать файлы внутри контейнеров? Я имею ввиду не только файлы настройки, но и саму файловую структуру проектов в контейнерах. Как известно, докер предназначен был изначально для линукса, однако, тема виртуальных машин и работы контейнеров плохо освещена в интернете для виндоус. Некоторые пишут, что для виндоус вообще не стоит поднимать контейнеры. Сколько не рыл, понятную инструкцию для чайников найти не удалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:
`docker run -it -v /path/to/host:/path/to/container <image_name> bash` для монтирования файловой системы хоста в контейнер. После этого должна появиться возможность редактирования файлов внутри контейнера напрямую через файловую систему хоста.

`/path/to/host` - путь на хосте, где находятся файлы, которые вы хотите использовать внутри контейнера.

`/path/to/container` - путь внутри контейнера, где будут расположены файлы из хоста.

`<image_name>` - имя образа, из которого вы хотите запустить контейнер.

ps. вообще такая инфа гуглится...